# React useMemo dependency array with extra dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

From the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

**Is it bad practice to add another value to the dependency array, even if it's not used in `computeExpensiveValue`?**

Example:

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b, c]);
```

I have a memoizedValue that needs to be recomputed when the state of `c` changes. My linter tells me it's an unnecessary dependency which leads me to believe there is an alternative solution that makes more sense...

The only alternative I can think of is storing `memoizedValue` as a state value, then wrap the `setMemoizedValue` in a useEffect hook that has `c` as a dependency.

Example:

```
const [stateNotMemo, setStateNotMemo] = useState({})

useEffect(() => setStateNotMemo(() => return {...someObject},[c])
```

Edit: Basically what I am trying to do is update the `memoizedValue` when I close out of a modal.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => {
    calculateNewValueWhenModalCloses(a,b);
},[a,b,showModal])

const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
}

const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
}

// Then some jsx that has two buttons. 
// one with onClick={handleCloseModal} (passed to modal component)
// and another with onClick={handleOpenModal}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can*, but it's a code smell. It indicates that `computeExpensiveValue` is impure and that its output depends on `c` in some way, despite not being an argument. If feasible, refactor it to pass `c` as an additional argument.

```
useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b, c), [a, b, c]);
```

Comment: I thought it smelled a little. :)

That's what I was thinking originally, the thing is, it doesn't really matter at all what the value of `c` is, It just needs to update whenever any change to state `c` happens. So it doesn't really depend on the value of `c` technically? Just when `c` changes. Idk, still feels funky.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual use case in an edit to your question? There's probably a better way to structure things, but more context is needed.

Comment: Edited the original post to include my use case. Hopefully, that makes things more clear!